# Moving all files from one directory to another using Python

Tags: python, directory, move

I want to move all text files from one folder to another folder using Python. I found this code:

```
import os, shutil, glob

dst = '/path/to/dir/Caches/com.apple.Safari/WebKitCache/Version\ 4/Blobs '
try:
    os.makedirs(/path/to/dir/Tumblr/Uploads) # create destination directory, if needed (similar to mkdir -p)
except OSError:
    # The directory already existed, nothing to do
    pass

for txt_file in glob.iglob('*.txt'):
    shutil.copy2(txt_file, dst)
```

I would want it to move all the files in the `Blob` folder.  I am not getting an error, but it is also not moving the files.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Try this:

```
import shutil
import os
    
source_dir = '/path/to/source_folder'
target_dir = '/path/to/dest_folder'
    
file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)
    
for file_name in file_names:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
```

Comment: Note: The above *will* move files recursively from source to destination.  Also, in my test, the above code is missing a trailing slash in both `source` and `dest1`.

Comment: does this move sub-directories (and/or the files inside them) into the destination folder?

Comment: @danielbrandstetter  shutil.move(src, dst): Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst).

Comment: You need '/' at the end of the paths `srouce` and `dest1`.
Also `shutil.move(source+f, dest1)` this should be `shutil.move(source+f, dest1+f)` to be extra secure. Otherwise all of `source+f` becomes a file with path `dest1`

Comment: So in summary, if you want subdirectories moved as well, use:

for f in files:
shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), os.path.join(dest1,f))

Answer (score 23):

Suprised this doesn't have an answer using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which was introduced in Python `3.4`.

Additionally, [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) was updated in Python `3.6` to accept a pathlib object. More details in this [PEP-0519](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/).

## Pathlib (moves files, does not copy)

```
from pathlib import Path

src_path = Path('/tmp').joinpath('files_to_move')
# ^ the same as /tmp/files_to_move
#   OR //tmp//files_to_move if on windows. 

for each_file in src_path.glob('*.*'): # grabs all files
    trg_path = src_path.parent # gets the parent of the folder 
    each_file.rename(trg_path.joinpath(each_file.name)) # moves to parent folder.
```

---

## Pathlib & shutil to copy files.

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

src_path = Path('/tmp').joinpath('files_to_move')
trg_path = src_path.parent # this would be '/tmp/' from the above example.

for src_file in src_path.glob('*.*'):
    shutil.copy(src_file, trg_path)
```

### Before (both examples)

[image]

### After (move example)

[image]

### After (copy example)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I think you mean here to do `Path(src_path).glob('*.*')`?

Comment: `Path` also implements a method called `iterdir`, in case you don't want to `.glob('*.*')` https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir

Comment: @emmagras nice catch, feel free to edit next time :) you also have `rglob` to trawl a directory structure.

Answer (score 8):

Please, take a look at implementation of the [copytree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#copytree-example) function which:

- List directory files with:

  `names = os.listdir(src)`
- Copy files with:

```py
for name in names:
  srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
  dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
  copy2(srcname, dstname)
```

Getting *dstname* is not necessary, because if destination parameter specifies a directory, the file will be copied into *dst* using the base filename from *srcname*.

Replace *copy2* by *move*.

Answer (score 6):

Copying the ".txt" file from one folder to another is very simple and question contains the logic. Only missing part is substituting with right information as below:

```
import os, shutil, glob

src_fldr = r"Source Folder/Directory path"; ## Edit this

dst_fldr = "Destiantion Folder/Directory path"; ## Edit this

try:
  os.makedirs(dst_fldr); ## it creates the destination folder
except:
  print "Folder already exist or some error";
```

below lines of code will copy the file with *.txt extension files from 
src_fldr to dst_fldr

```
for txt_file in glob.glob(src_fldr+"\\*.txt"):
    shutil.copy2(txt_file, dst_fldr);
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick. Also read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) of the shutil module to choose the function that fits your needs (shutil.copy(), shutil.copy2(), shutil.copyfile() or shutil.move()).

```
import glob, os, shutil

source_dir = '/path/to/dir/with/files' #Path where your files are at the moment
dst = '/path/to/dir/for/new/files' #Path you want to move your files to
files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(source_dir, "*.txt"))
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy2(file, dst)
```

Comment: but where do i define the new destination for the txt files?

Answer (score 4):

```
import shutil 
import os 
import logging

source = '/var/spools/asterisk/monitor' 
dest1 = '/tmp/'


files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
        shutil.move(source+f, dest1)

logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s
- %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logging.info('directories moved')
```

A little bit cooked code with log feature. You can also configure this to run at some period of time using crontab.

```
* */1 * * * python /home/yourprogram.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

runs every hour! cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 if os.path.exists(source_dir):
    try:
        file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
            os.makedirs(target_dir)
        for file_name in file_names:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
    except OSError as e:
        print("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
else:
    log.debug(" Directory not exist {}".format(source_dir))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Move files with filter( using Path, os,shutil modules):**

```html
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import os

src_path ='/media/shakil/New Volume/python/src'
trg_path ='/media/shakil/New Volume/python/trg'

for src_file in Path(src_path).glob('*.txt*'):
    shutil.move(os.path.join(src_path,src_file),trg_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if I wanted to move all .txt files from one location to another ( on a Windows OS for instance ) I would do it something like this:

```
import shutil
import os,glob

inpath = 'R:/demo/in' 
outpath = 'R:/demo/out'

os.chdir(inpath)
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):

    shutil.move(inpath+'/'+file,outpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def copy_myfile_dirOne_to_dirSec(src, dest, ext): 

    if not os.path.exists(dest):    # if dest dir is not there then we create here
        os.makedirs(dest);
        
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        if item.endswith(ext):
            s = os.path.join(src, item);
            fd = open(s, 'r');
            data = fd.read();
            fd.close();
            
            fname = str(item); #just taking file name to make this name file is destination dir     
            
            d = os.path.join(dest, fname);
            fd = open(d, 'w');
            fd.write(data);
            fd.close();
    
    print("Files are copyed successfully")
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

This Script find Docx Files in Directory and create Folder For Docx Files and Move Them into created Directory

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

docfiles=glob.glob("./**/*.docx" , recursive=True)
if docfiles:
    docdir = os.path.join("./DOCX")
    os.makedirs(docdir , exist_ok = True)
    for docfile in docfiles:
        if docfile in docdir:
            pass
        else:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(docfile),docdir)
            print("Files Moved")
```

Answer (score -2):

If you prefer to use linux command, os.system() is a great option.

```
import os
old_dir = 'path1/'
new_dir = 'path2/'
os.system(f'mv {old_dir} {new_dir}')
```